# How to get 1st nested object into a 2nd level nested object controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a Character model that has a show page. On the show page, I have a loop of comments that are dynamically generated via a partial. In that comments partial, I have another partial for votes, which contains voting buttons. Naturally, I want to allow votes on comments.

I am unsure how to get the comment object into the votes controller  (or VotesController module, depending on the implementation) for creating a vote.

Getting the character object id to the votes controller is simple enough, since the actual view is the character show page, but obtaining a specific comment's id that is genrated from a partial, by clicking a vote button in a partial that is nested in the comments partial is causing me to draw a blank for the syntax of accessing that comment.

(I am using acts_as_votable for votes, and acts_as_commentable for comments.)

---

**app/views/characters/show.html.haml**

```
= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @comments, as: :comment
```

**app/views/comments/_form.html.haml**

```
.comment{ :id => "comment-#{comment.id}" }
  %hr

  = render partial: 'votes/vote_comment'

  %h4
    #comment body
```

**app/views/votes/_vote_comment.html.haml**

```
.vote-comment-buttons
  = link_to image_tag("upvote.png"), votes_upvote_path(), method: :post, remote: true
  = link_to image_tag("downvote.png"), votes_downvote_path(), method: :post, remote: true
```

**app/controllers/votes.html.haml**

```
VotesController < ApplicationController

  def upvote
    # Need the specific comment or comment id whose vote button was clicked.
  end

  def downvote
    # Need the specific comment or comment id whose vote button was clicked.
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here are the basic tips:

1. You can not pass ruby objects through HTTP, but you can pass `id` and `type` of them to build them in your controller.
2. Even when you type something like `comment_path(comment)`, only `id` of that comment is passed to your action. That is easily checked by observing your action code (it should contain something like `Comment.find(params[:id])`).
3. Passing any desired amout of additional parameters can be done with just providing them to your route helpers, like that: `some_voting_path(commentable_id: 14, commentable_type: 'character')`.
4. You can access that params inside of your action with `params['commentable_type']` or whatever values you pass with your URL. In case you follow passing `id` and `type` approach, you should be able to do some metaprogramming:

   ```
   def upvote_method
     model = params[:commentable_type].camelize.constantize # => e.g., Post
     object = model.find(params[:commentable_id]) # => post object
     # here goes your inner logics
   end
   ```
5. Beware that in case you send your request using `GET` method, these params are gonna be shown in your browser URL. However, you should not use `GET` for your purpose here, as voting changes the state of objects in your database.